# Azure Backup is failing with "VM is not in a state that allows backups." for Multiple Vms

Tags: azure, backup, azure-backup-vault

Azure Backup is failing with "VM is not in a state that allows backups." for multiple VMs (almost 100)

Can anyone give a clue about the error and fix for that?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

VM is not in a state that allows backups.

Check if VM is in a transient state between Running and Shut down. If it is, wait for the VM state to be one of them and trigger backup again.
If the VM is a Linux VM and uses [Security Enhanced Linux] kernel module, you need to exclude the Linux Agent path(/var/lib/waagent) from security policy to make sure backup extension gets installed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vms-troubleshoot

Comment: As said this is already checked.Please suggest apart from docs available in google.

Comment: If you are looking for a solution or cause, no one can provide that for you.  
The error indicates that the VMs were not in a running state at the time backup was initiated.  

You can confirm the state of a VM by running:  
`(Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName <rgname> -Name <vmname> -Status).Statuses`  

If you have confirmed that a VM is in a running state you can manually try backup. You will have to investigate why VM was not in a running state.

Comment: Vm was in a runnning state .We can able to login to VM.
tried manual backup as well.
Still we are facing same issue.

Comment: If the status is running and the VM is not Linux VM using SELinux or already has an exception for waagent then you need to engage Microsoft Azure Recovery Service team for assistance as the issue might not be on your side.

Comment: Oh Sure ..! Thank you .Will do it.

Comment: 1. Can you confirm the Azure VM Agent is able to communicate to Azure VM?
2. Can you confirm Azure VM “Extensions” provision state is Succeeded or not?
3. If possible restart Azure VM from OS and Azure Portal and check the error status.
4. Trigger a manual backup. monitor the progress and share the status with us.